# Android Studio : A scaling graph in bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Just started learning graphics in Android Studio and started out by making a growing graph(x^2). It turned out pretty well, but it goes out of the bitmap box quite fast and I was wondering if it is possible to start scaling it while it tries to grow outside the boundaries.

[Here](https://www.csgocrash.com/play/1) is a good example of what I mean. Whenever the graph line starts to exit the boundaries of the box, all the graph starts to scale.

Is that possible to do with bitmap or any other way in Android Studio? And if so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty open ended but IMO this all depends on what you're trying to do and how big everything can scale.

Typically what I would say is that your bitmap shouldn't scale up, your graph should scale down. This keeps the memory footprint of the bitmap small which will be important to run on low memory devices. IMO you should use [paths](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and then draw them on your canvas and change the stroke to make them smaller as needed. Then they can scale up and it wont matter if it draws offscreen as it's not actually making the bitmap bigger. To learn how to do that you should check out Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)!

If you want to use a bitmap then You should read the suggestions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) as well. Also you'll probably have to get into [tiling/region decoding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) in order to load everything efficiently when zooming in on the image:

Comment: I understood that I need to somehow scale the graph down whenever it attempts to go out of boundaries, but I have no idea how to use paths or whatever in order to accomplish that.